# trying to use c# to install .NET 4 GAC DLL

Tags: c#-4.0, gac

Uptil now, we've been using C# to install GAC DLL's to the GAC without any issues

```
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish p = 
  new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish();

p.GacInstall(filePath);
```

However, we tried using the same code to install a .NET 4.0 GAC DLL. It does not give any error and says that the GAC is installed.

However, when I look in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly` folder I do not see the GAC being installed. Also, when I look up the event viewer on the Server it shows me a warning

> "Source: COM+ SOAP Services Installation in the global assembly failed: `<GACDLL_PATH>`

Is there any way I can install a .NET 4.0 GAC DLL into the GAC programtically using C#?

Comment: What is the exact message and stack trace?

Comment: In the event viewer "Installation in the global assembly cache failed D:\GBM\GACFILES\Templates.dll" the source is COM+ SOAP Services. I did not get any error while running the program. the message it gave me is ....Installing GAC D:\GAC\GACFILES\Templates.dll

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue
I rebuilt my C# project with the target framework 4.0. 
Previously I was trying to install .NET 4 GAC DLL with a c# project that was built with the target framework 3.5...

After the project was rebuilt with .NET 4.0 framework I was able to install .NET 4 gac dll. Also, this is backward compatible i.e. you can install GAC DLL's created with previous versions of the .NET framework.